# Managing enums with Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest, spring-rest

I've a project with Spring Boot 1.5.7, Spring Data REST, Hibernate, HATEOAS, Spring validation.

I'm really struggling trying to manage enums. I need two simple things:

1. get the list of items of a specific enum (HTTP REST)
2. Sent an enum as parameter into a HTTP REST calls

I'm using Spring Data REST, so a lot of the work should be made from it.

My enum is something basic like:

```
public enum TransitCertificateStatus {
    PENDING, USED, CANCELED, ARCHIVED
}
```

this enum is used into a bean:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(TransitCertificateListener.class)
public class TransitCertificate extends AbstractEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5978999252424024545L;

    @NotNull(message = "{NotNull.transitcertificate.status}")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TransitCertificateStatus status = TransitCertificateStatus.PENDING;
```

To exposes enum items to the client I created a custom controller:

```
@Api(tags = "TransitCertificate Entity")
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/transitCertificates")
public class TransitCertificateController {
    private Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/states", produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> getTransitCertificateStates() {
        Resources<TransitCertificateStatus> resources = new Resources<TransitCertificateStatus>(
                Arrays.asList(TransitCertificateStatus.values()));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(resources);
    }
```

This works fine, and the http response is:

```
 {
  "_embedded": {
    "transitCertificateStatuses": [
      "In attesa",
      "Utilizzato",
      "Annullato",
      "Archiviato"
    ]
  }
}
```

Note the items are translated because I set these values into rest-messages.properties and Spring Data REST takes care of the conversion.

```
server.model.enums.TransitCertificateStatus.PENDING = In attesa
server.model.enums.TransitCertificateStatus.USED = Utilizzato
server.model.enums.TransitCertificateStatus.CANCELED = Annullato
server.model.enums.TransitCertificateStatus.ARCHIVED = Archiviato
```

So far, everything is as expected.
Now I need to get a filtered list of by bean `TransitCertificate` and I am exposing directly the repository as a REST resource:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public interface TransitCertificateRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<TransitCertificate, Long> {

 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Query("SELECT t FROM TransitCertificate t WHERE (:code IS NULL OR code=:code) AND (:date IS NULL OR DATE(createdDate)=DATE(:date)) AND (:text IS NULL OR text LIKE CONCAT('%',:text,'%')) AND (:from IS NULL OR t.from LIKE CONCAT('%',:from,'%')) AND (:customerName IS NULL OR customerName LIKE CONCAT('%',:customerName,'%')) AND (:states IS NULL OR status IN (:states)) ")
public Page<TransitCertificate> findAllByParameters(@Param("code") @RequestParam(value = "code", required = false) String code,
        @Param("date") @RequestParam(value = "date", required = false) Instant date,
        @Param("text") @RequestParam(value = "text", required = false) String text,
        @Param("from") @RequestParam(value = "from", required = false) String from,
        @Param("customerName") @RequestParam(value = "customerName", required = false) String customerName,
        @Param("states") @RequestParam(value = "states", required = false) List<TransitCertificateStatus> states, Pageable pageable);


@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Query("SELECT t FROM TransitCertificate t WHERE (:#{#filter} IS NULL OR t.status=:#{#filter.status}) ")
public Page<TransitCertificate> findAllByParameters2(@RequestBody @RequestParam(value="filter") @Param("filter") TransitCertificateFilter filter,
        Pageable pageable);
```

The client sends enum translated values as the server replied in the first instance (it doesn't know anything else about the enum).

**First approach**

In the first approach I used a `List<TransitCertificateStatus>` as parameter but unfortunately I have an exception:

```
Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.Resources["_embedded"])
```

So I tried a different approach.

**Second approach**

This time I created a bean that is the filter and contains all parameters that should be filtered in the query.

```
    public class TransitCertificateFilter implements Serializable {

    private TransitCertificateStatus status;

    public TransitCertificateStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(TransitCertificateStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

In the method `findAllByParameters2` so I use SpEL to get the property `status` from the bean the client sent.

This is the request:

```
{
"status":"Annullato"
}
```

And this is the exception I've back:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2017-10-12T15:46:20.292+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException",
  "message": "EL1007E: Property or field 'status' cannot be found on null",
  "path": "/api/v1/transitCertificates/search/findAllByParameters2"
}
```

I searched for a while info about this but I didn't find anything useful. Is someone able to put me on the right path?